# Color page switcher with jQuery and cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I need help to add cookie here, im try but can't , don't know how to add... any help ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("li.black_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass("bg1");
    });

    $("li.blue_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg3").addClass("bg2");
    });

    $("li.red_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg2").addClass("bg3");
    }); 

});
```

Here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/jhMfw/ but without cookie

Comment: See https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very simple usage, I recommend you the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and the [tutorial here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) to learn how to use it.

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/jhMfw/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li.black_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass("bg1");
        $.cookie('mycookie','bg1');
    });

    $("li.blue_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg3").addClass("bg2");
        $.cookie('mycookie','bg2');
    });

    $("li.red_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg2").addClass("bg3");
        $.cookie('mycookie','bg3');
    }); 

    if ($.cookie('mycookie')) {
        $('.main').addClass($.cookie('mycookie'));
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [jQuery.cookie()](http://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
$.cookie('bckground-color', 'bg1');//set a cookie
$.cookie('bckground-color');//retrieve a cookie

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var startClass = $.cookie('bckGround');
    $(".main").addClass(startClass);
    $("li.black_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass("bg1");
         $.cookie('bckGround', 'bg1');
    });

    $("li.blue_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg3").addClass("bg2");
         $.cookie('bckGround', 'bg2');
    });

    $("li.red_c").click( function(){ $
        (".main").removeClass("bg1 , bg2").addClass("bg3");
         $.cookie('bckGround', 'bg3');
    }); 

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

better you create a themed css, that you replace by clicking on your button.

css

black.css

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
}
```

blue.css

```
.button {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

red.css

```
.button {
    background-color: red;
}
```

in the head of your html file you will add a script tag like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/black.css" name="branded"/>
```

and your javascript:

```
var cookieName = 'current-branding';

function changeBranding(branding) {
    $.cookie(cookieName, branding);
    $('head link[name=branded]').attr('href', 'css/' + branding + '.css');

}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if( $.cookie(cookieName)) {
        changeBranding($.cookie(cookieName));
    }

    $("li.black_c").click( function(){ $
       changeBranding('black');
    });

    $("li.blue_c").click( function(){ $
       changeBranding('blue');
    });

    $("li.red_c").click( function(){ $
       changeBranding('red');
    }); 

});
```